# Parsing xml with same tags and different attributes

Tags: python, lxml

I have a network file created from osm using Netconvert. The root element is edge with different attributes. For example, in the first part of the file, the edges are organized as follows.

```
<edge id=":367367171_1" function="internal">
    <lane id=":367367171_1_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="5.56" length="15.86" shape="7413.68,8096.43 7409.39,8098.94 7406.50,8098.93 7405.03,8096.39 7404.96,8091.32"/>
</edge>
<edge id=":367367171_2" function="internal">
    <lane id=":367367171_2_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="5.56" length="9.40" shape="7413.68,8096.43 7412.34,8099.01 7410.83,8099.98 7409.14,8099.36 7407.28,8097.13"/>
</edge>
<edge id=":367367171_3" function="internal">
    <lane id=":367367171_3_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="5.56" length="5.56" shape="7408.25,8091.65 7407.28,8097.13"/>
</edge>
<edge id=":367367171_4" function="internal">
    <lane id=":367367171_4_0" index="0" disallow="tram rail_urban rail rail_electric ship" speed="5.56" length="5.69" shape="7408.25,8091.65 7408.69,8097.32"/>
</edge>
```

In the second part, the attributes of the edge file changes and it looks like below

```
<edge id="102323265#13" from="1181188708" to="1181188720" priority="1" type="highway.cycleway">
    <lane id="102323265#13_0" index="0" allow="bicycle" speed="5.56" length="1.96" width="1.00" shape="14310.67,8986.24 14309.63,8984.59"/>
</edge>
<edge id="102323265#2" from="2577245263" to="1721713370" priority="1" type="highway.cycleway" shape="14903.54,9214.01 14891.64,9210.58 14796.11,9178.46 14789.16,9175.24">
    <lane id="102323265#2_0" index="0" allow="bicycle" speed="5.56" length="113.82" width="1.00" shape="14898.81,9213.21 14891.49,9211.10 14795.93,9178.98 14791.04,9176.72"/>
</edge>
<edge id="102323265#3" from="1721713370" to="1193980046" priority="1" type="highway.cycleway" shape="14789.16,9175.24 14783.34,9171.87 14779.91,9168.83 14776.75,9165.32">
    <lane id="102323265#3_0" index="0" allow="bicycle" speed="5.56" length="9.86" width="1.00" shape="14786.63,9174.41 14783.01,9172.31 14779.55,9169.24 14778.85,9168.47"/>
</edge>
<edge id="102323265#4" from="1193980046" to="1193980047" priority="1" type="highway.cycleway" shape="14776.75,9165.32 14764.89,9151.27 14762.54,9144.61">
    <lane id="102323265#4_0" index="0" allow="bicycle" speed="5.56" length="20.05" width="1.00" shape="14774.71,9163.77 14764.40,9151.55 14763.05,9147.72"/>
</edge>
<edge id="102323265#5" from="1193980047" to="1193980057" priority="1" type="highway.cycleway" shape="14762.54,9144.61 14760.31,9140.42 14753.93,9131.92 14749.20,9127.42 14743.90,9123.46 14738.81,9120.77 14731.67,9118.17 14707.61,9110.82">
    <lane id="102323265#5_0" index="0" allow="bicycle" speed="5.56" length="60.21" width="1.00" shape="14760.51,9141.98 14759.82,9140.67 14753.49,9132.25 14748.82,9127.82 14743.57,9123.90 14738.55,9121.26 14731.49,9118.68 14710.43,9112.25"/>
</edge>
```

As you can see, there are different attributes for the element edge. When I try to access the elements using the following code,

```
for elem in netFile.iter(tag='edge'):
    print(elem.attrib['from'])
```

I get a `KeyError:'from'`

When I change the key to `'function'` instead of `'from'`, the code prints me multiple lines of `'internal'` and when it approaches the end of the first part, it again throw me

`KeyError: 'function'`.

I understand that I have to selectively iterate through the edges in which the attribute `'from'` is present, but have no idea on how to proceed. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method for dictionaries is very helpful in these situations because it returns `None` when a key isn't found in a `dict`.

```
for elem in netFile.iter(tag='edge'):
    if elem.attrib.get('from'):
        # from stuff
    else:
        # other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this lxml so there are much simpler ways to *to selectively iterate through the edges in which the attribute 'from' is present* , you can use the following xpath to find all the edges that have the *from* attribute:

```
for e in root.xpath("//edge[@from]")
```

If you want to check for having multiple attributes you can use *and*:

```
 .xpath("//edge[@from and @function]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could detect wich part of the file you are proccessing by the presence of the attributes e.g.:

```
# The !required! attributes for each part
part1_attributes = ["id", "function"]
part2_attributes = ["id", "from", "to", "priority", "type"]

for elem in netFile.iter(tag='edge'):
    if all([attr in elem.attrib for attr in part1_attributes]):
        # part 1
        print("function: " + elem.attrib["function"])
    elif all([attr in elem.attrib for attr in part2_attributes]):
        # part 2
        print("from: " + elem.attrib["from"])
    else:
        print("Unknown part found while parsing xml")
        # or raise Exception("message...") or exit program etc.
```

If one of the edges suddendly does not contain one of the attributes this will sort it out and return an error (or just print it and continue), instead of returning `None` like in [gr1zzly be4r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37812639/2607571).

Comment: the solution is elegant and exactly fits my needs. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help :)